# AngularJS two way binding between controller and directive not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Ok, so I have seen a bunch of these questions here, though I must be missing something trivial.

Please have a look at this [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/pAsoY5p9T68tnWPtgkEv?p=preview)

In it there is a simple controller that sets an image url. There is also a directive that loads in the template from a script tag.

I have set it up so that the directive changes the `imageUrl` after 2 seconds though I don't see any of the two-way binding occurring. the image should change, as well as the text.

Can anyone please explain what I am missing here?

i also tried the timeout in the controller too.

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that you are using setTimeout to change the model. Angular is not aware of this since it happens "outside" of Angular. Instead, use Angular's $timeout:

http://plnkr.co/edit/9qYpFdnlaOy3QBDDkBUQ?p=preview

There is a way to manually tell Angular that you have made a change to the model by calling `scope.$apply()` after setting `scope.imageUrl` in the setTimeout, but it's better to use $timeout since it will happen automatically.

Comment: Balls... thanks. I only put the timeout to check it was working, though now learned something new :) - will mark as answered shortly.